# Specify a library version in zappa deploy

Tags: python, numpy, version, zappa, python-zappa

I am working on a very barebones zappa app that imports a few libraries and displays a success string.

`numpy` is giving me issues and one solution I've read is to revert from the current version (1.21.2) to a previous version (1.19.4). My process is:

- undeploy the zappa app
- uninstall numpy from my virtualenv
- reinstall numpy==1.19.4 inn virtualenv
- deploy zappa app

But when I deploy, I continue to get a 502 error, and `zappa tail` shows that the deployed environment is *still* running 1.21.2.

How do I force the zappa deployment to use the desired version of `numpy` in my deploys?

Comment: Did pip freeze confirm it was 1.19.4 in the virtual env?

Comment: @BrianDestura : yup!